# JS: fastest way to return 2 numbers from function?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there a way to outperform the following approach? (the type of a and b is known - unsigned int 32 bit):

```
function f() {
    var a = /*calculate a*/;
    var b = /*calculate b*/;
    return [a, b];
}
```

Will this be faster? Yes, I know, the following code is awful. But the idea is to avoid creating new objects (like the returned array in first example).

```
// set of general-purpose registers for UINT32 values.
var global_registers = new Uint32Array(256);

function f() {
    global_registers[0] = a;
    global_registers[1] = b;
}

// Usage:
f();

//use the global_registers[0] and global_registers[1].
```

Comment: I’d assume that setting properties of a `Uint32Array` performs some type checking which setting properties of an `Array` doesn’t.

Comment: If you don't  mind the global variables then it should be nanoscopically faster.  I just made that word up.

Comment: "Faster" in the sense of how long the code takes to run, or how long it takes you to debug it...

Comment: Typed arrays are good for performing calculations with the stored data; I doubt it will give you a significant boost on performance if you solely use it as "registers".

Comment: You can test it by simply adding a timer to the function. I don't think that there is a need for posting this as a question.

Answer (score 4):

From the two versions of code you have provided, the second is faster. But that does not mean the use of typed arrays is making the difference. You have also switched to global variables, mutate those instead of creating new entries, and don't let your function return anything.

Here are performance tests for these variants:

1. Your original array solution
2. Use of a plain object instead of an array

   ```
   function f_obj() {
       var a = 1;
       var b = 2;
       return {a, b};
   }
   ```
3. Use of a global plain object passed as argument

   ```
   function f_obj_inplace(obj) {
       var a = 1;
       var b = 2;
       obj.a = a
       obj.b = b;
   }
   ```
4. Your original global "register" solution
5. Use of a standard global object

   ```
   var global_obj = { a: 0, b: 0};

   function f_glob_obj() {
       var a = 1;
       var b = 2;
       global_obj.a = a;
       global_obj.b = b;
   }
   ```

```js
//////////////////////////////////////
function f_arr() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    return [a, b];
}

//////////////////////////////////////
function f_obj() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    return {a, b};
}

//////////////////////////////////////
var global_registers = new Uint32Array(256);

function f_glob_reg() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    global_registers[0] = a;
    global_registers[1] = b;
}

//////////////////////////////////////
var global_obj = { a: 0, b: 0};

function f_glob_obj() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    global_obj.a = a;
    global_obj.b = b;
}

var iterations = 1000000;
var o, result;
/////////////////////
var start = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    o = f_arr();
    result = o[0];
}
console.log('f_arr', (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2));
/////////////////////
var start = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    o = f_obj();
    result = o.a;
}
console.log('f_obj', (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2));
/////////////////////
var obj = { a: 0, b: 0 };
var start = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    f_obj(obj);
    result = obj.a;
}
console.log('f_obj_inplace', (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2));
/////////////////////
var start = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    f_glob_reg();
    result = global_registers[0];
}
console.log('f_glob_reg', (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2));
/////////////////////
var start = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    f_glob_obj();
    result = global_obj.a;
}
console.log('f_glob_obj', (performance.now() - start).toFixed(2));
/////////////////////
```

Here is a typical run I have on Firefox and Chrome:

```
   Function       | Firefox 47 | Chrome 52
------------------+------------+----------
1. f_arr          |    501     |   206 
2. f_obj          |    202     |   172
3. f_obj_inplace  |     17     |    69
4. f_glob_reg     |     19     |    34
5. f_glob_obj     |     22     |    31
```

The results should be taken with some error margin, as they vary on every run depending on PC load.

These results reveal that the plain object solution (2) is faster than the array solution (1). Notably on Firefox the array solution is much slower.

We can also see that the use of global variables which are mutated in-place (3, 4 and 5) gives a tremendous performance gain. Chrome does still have some performance loss when passing the global object as a function argument (3), while for Firefox it makes hardly any difference.

But more importantly, from the last two measurements, we see the untyped, global variable solution is about just as fast as the original typed global variable solution.

#### Remarks

The use of global variables from within a function is not advisable for known reasons: it makes code less modular, harder to read and harder to debug.

If you want to take the performance benefit of storing data in the same place each time, then pass the variable as argument to the function: the performance loss of doing that seems to be within acceptable limits (although Firefox seems to deal better with it than Chrome).

It might be too restrictive that the function always writes to the same global variables, destroying the previous result. If you would end up copying the results elsewhere to save them from being overwritten, you will thus add overhead again.

The use of typed arrays is not really a decisive factor in performance.

#### Conclusion

The above results and considerations lead me to suggest the 3rd option as the way to go:

```
function f_obj_inplace(obj) {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    obj.a = a
    obj.b = b;
}
```

You don't have the ugly direct access to global variables, and don't use typed arrays. But you do use in-place mutation, and plain objects instead of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd throw this out there since it's quite interesting...

What if you could return a single number that could be used to obtain two original values?

If return time is your only concern but calculation time is not, you might want to consider the cantor pairing function

This is a function that takes two whole numbers as input and returns a value that can later be used to reverse the process and retrieve the two original numbers.

Naturally the calculations required to implement this will produce some kind of overhead, but if it's the return time that's critical it might be useful.

You can find examples online, here's an implementation in php:

https://gist.github.com/hannesl/8031402

ETA - above link also links to a javascript implementation. I've never tried this to be honest but I remember reading about it, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is more professional. Global variables should only be used sparingly in an application. Objects that may exist locally without affecting the result should be used in a local context.

Global variables mess up our memory, our scope. You can check script execution time for both approach via developer consoles on major browsers and no one will have to tell you that the first approach is preferable.

JavaScript is a C-Like programming language. So lets look at how its C origin behaves:

When we create variables, our variables occupy an address in our register and the computer keeps a local store of its location in memory to access it later.

When we create arrays on the other hand, we only store the address of the first element (pointers). Our computer does not bother knowing the location of both variables. Only the location of the first variable is pointed to. This enables faster access to our data and consumes less resources.

Imagine a situation where we want to return 100 numbers from our function. Going by our argument, we can see clearly that its much more efficient to return an array.

PLEASE NOTE: Both approach are good and fast. I am only giving reasons why the first approach should be considered whenever it can.

Comment: Your answer is speculative: "When we create arrays on the other hand, we only store the address of the first element " --- but it's an allocation. So to return "just a pointer" you need to perform an expensive heap allocation before.

Comment: "Going by our argument, we can see clearly that its much more efficient to return an array." --- your "argument" is not proven by anything though.

Comment: *"JavaScript is a C-Like programming language"*: while this similarity may apply to syntax, they are certainly not comparable when it comes to their data storage implementations.